# ASP.NET Entity Framework API Controller Add method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Entity Framework API Controller that was generated, I am now trying to add a new method to it:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(LCPreview))]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateEmail(string email)
{
    LCPreview lCPreview = db.Data.Find(5);
    if (lCPreview == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(lCPreview);
}
```

but when I run this, I get this error:

> The request is invalid. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetLCPreview(Int32)' in 'Astoria.Controllers.PreviewLCAPIController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: did you check the object returned from db.Data.Find call? It might be having a null value for id field.

Comment: I put in a a break point, its not hitting that new method at all

Comment: route conflict. it is hitting another route that matched the request. Show how you configure your routes setup. and the url being requested

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like it is hitting GetLCPreview(Int32) with a null parameter.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and and assume you are using a GET request to try and hit this method. By default, I believe that any route that *doesn't* have get in the name (or is marked with an HTTPGet attibute) will default to POST. So you will either need to mark this as a GET request or change your call to a POST

Comment: I posted my routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

via convention-based routing the route table is unable to differentiate between the two actions and is selecting the `GetLCPreview` action based on `Get` prefix convention.

Given that your route configuration is already enabling attribute routing this means that paramater constraints can be used to help differentiate the routes.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/PreviewLCAPI")]
public class PreviewLCAPIController : ApiController {

    //GET api/PreviewLCAPI/5 <- only when the value is an int will it match.
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLCPreview(int id) { ... }

    //GET api/PreviewLCAPI/someone@email.com/
    [Route("{email}"]
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LCPreview))]
    public IHttpActionResult ValidateEmail(string email) { ... }
}
```

Note that the dot (.) in the email will cause you some issues if entered without the slash (/) at the end. The framework will think it's looking for a file and error out.

If the intention was to send the email address then use POST and include email in the body.

```
//POST api/PreviewLCAPI
[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(LCPreview))]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateEmail([FromBody] string email) { ... }
```

sending it in the request body avoid any issues with the email format in the url.